# Signing Ropsten transactions with

Tags: web3js, javascript, infura, hdwalletprovider

I am trying to sign transactions using the Web3 HDWalletProvider package and an infura API. I am using the following code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const Web3HDWalletProvider = require("web3-hdwallet-provider");
const mnemonic = "12 words"

var httpProvider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/[API]');
var provider = new Web3HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, httpProvider);
```

I get the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I have a Dapp that I compile in Remix and I have been using Metamask to confirm transactions but I want to upload several thousands smart contracts in a batch and confirming individually is not a practical option. I would rather not convert my project to truffle if possible. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Phil

Comment: Are you running this script with node, or with a browser? AFAIK, `require` is for node only.

Comment: I am trying to run it in a browser, hence the problem. However, I am confused, how can I run it then? How do I run it with node? I would normally run the app by running npm run dev. How do I provision the Provider from Node?

Comment: `node yourFileName.js`